# Extending kotlinx.html dsl to create functions that include bootstrap classes

Tags: kotlin, dsl

I'm looking to create a library that extends kotlinx.html and will include functions that have default css classes.

The goal is to be able to use a function `row{}` instead of having to type `div(classes = "row"){}` each time. I would like to create these functions for a lot more commonly used Bootstrap classes.

In my example I use the `DIV` class to create a `row` function

The original `div` function:

```
@HtmlTagMarker
fun FlowContent.div(classes : String? = null, block : DIV.() -> Unit = {}) : Unit = DIV(attributesMapOf("class", classes), consumer).visit(block)
```

The first function I created has the `row` class set instead of `null.

```
@HtmlTagMarker
fun FlowContent.row(classes: String? = "row", block: DIV.() -> Unit = {}): Unit = DIV(attributesMapOf("class", classes), consumer).visit(block)
```

But this seems to be very restrictive, since the user of this function won't be able to add any additional css classes.

Therefore I put the `row` class in the `DIV` constructor as a string template. This way it can still be extended.

```
@HtmlTagMarker
fun FlowContent.row(classes: String? = "", block: DIV.() -> Unit = {}): Unit = DIV(attributesMapOf("class", "row $classes"), consumer).visit(block)
```

Does this seem like the right approach, or is it better to do this another way.

## Update

From the kotlinx.html documentation, I also found this approach.

```
fun DIV.row(block: DIV.() -> Unit) = div(classes = "row") { block() }
```

I must say that it looks very clean.

Comment: "Does this seem like the right approach" Did you test it?

Comment: @Mast I did test it, and it works. but I'm wondering if I'm not taking it too lightly or if I'm overthinking here